# How to make an attribute of multiple enumerations? schema XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, attributes, schema, restriction

im tring to make a database where i have the release date of some products in Japan, North America, And European Union.
I want to make it the way that if some date is repeated in the same product i can group the zones in one element, like this:

```
<releasedate>
     <zone zone="JP">30/08/1987</zone>
     <zone zone="NA|EU">22/11/1987</zone>
</releasedate>
```

In the schema i have the following code:

```
<xsd:attribute name="zone">
 <xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
   <xsd:enumeration value="JP"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="NA"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="EU"/>
   </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
 </xsd:attribute>
```

also tried making a pattern like "JP|NA|UE" and "(JP|NA|UE){1,3}". none works for me, i dont know if im using wrong the way to separate values, but i tried the pipe | and also with spaces in the attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a `xsd:simpleType`:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="location">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:pattern value="((^|\|)(JP|NA|EU))+$"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

The regex inside `pattern value` will match values like `JP`, `JP|NA`, `JP|NA|EU` and all other possible combinations.

Then you just have to restrict the attribute's value to `location`:

```
<xsd:attribute name="zone" type="location"/>
```